# Rotation effect with background-positon

Tags: javascript, css, anime.js

I need to create a rotating paste effect. For this I downloaded `animejs`. I placed the points where I need to stop for the rotation effect.

I also set up the scope, when the user sees the block, then the rotation occurs.

The problem is that I can't adjust the smoothness, I need to create a rotation effect, but because of the `background-positon`, the movement effect is obtained.

I can only use this image and this property, how can I do that?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rotate-pasta-ydglco)

Comment: What d you want it to look like?

Comment: @AHaworth [Like than pasta](http://www.presi-dent.ru)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to use `anime.js` here and why, but it can be done with pure CSS/JS easily:

```js
const el = document.getElementById("App");

const observer = new window.IntersectionObserver(
  ([entry]) => el.classList.toggle('spin', entry.isIntersecting),
  {root: null, threshold: .2}
);

observer.observe(el);
```

```css
#App {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 40.67vh;
  margin: 23em auto;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/EI2qVf1.jpeg") no-repeat 0 0 / 5500% 100%;
}

.spin {
  animation: spin 2s steps(54) infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {background-position: 100%}
}
```

```html
Scroll down
<div id="App"></div>
```

Comment: How do I create the full 360 scroll effect? To avoid a reversal?

Comment: @Frallen, please read on [`CSS animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation), then remove `alternate` option. The answer has been updated.